# Dropzone: How to get dropzone div inside which removefile is clicked on some thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using multiple dropzone elements inside one html page to upload different type of images. When user uploads some image, an hidden input containing filename(returned from server after uploading) is appended to the corresponding div.But when user clicks on remove file on one of the thumbnails, i want to remove the corresponding hidden input from the corresponding dropzone div. here is the code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var preImage = [];
            <?php if( isset($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) ? !empty($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) : false ){
                $preImage = explode(",", $listing[0]['listing_original_image'] );
                foreach ($preImage as $image ){
                    $imageArr[] =  array(
                        "name" => base_url('/uploads/listing/1/') . "/" .trim($image),
                        "size" => 1,
                        "type" => "image/jpeg"
                        );
                }
            }?>
            <?php if( isset($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) ? !empty($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) : false ){ ?>
            var mockFile = <?php echo json_encode($imageArr); ?>
            <?php } ?>
          //  var mockFile = [{ name: "logo.thumbnail.png", size: 1, type: 'image/jpeg' },{ name: "thumbnail.png", size: 1, type: 'image/jpeg' }];

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            var dzo = $("#thumbnail_dropzone").dropzone({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('Upload/uploadListingImages'); ?>",
                addRemoveLinks : true,
                acceptedFiles : "image/*",
                paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                init: function(){
                    var dp = this;
                    dp.on('addedfile', function(file){
                        // alert(file);
                    });
                    dp.on('success', function(file, response){
                        $("#thumbnail_dropzone").append($('<input type="hidden" name="listing_images[]" value="'+response.aFileName+'" />'));
                    });
                    dp.on('removedfile', function(file){
                       // code

                    });
                    <?php if( isset($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) ? !empty($listing[0]['listing_original_image']) : false ){ ?>
                            // console.log(mockFile);
                        for(var i=0; i<mockFile.length; i++){
                            this.options.addedfile.call(this, mockFile[i]);
                            //this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, "http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png");
                            this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile[i], mockFile[i].name);
                            mockFile[i].previewElement.classList.add('dz-success');
                            mockFile[i].previewElement.classList.add('dz-complete');
                        }
                    <?php } ?>
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you set up event handlers for `added_file`, `success` and `removed_file`.
On success you created an hidden input file with the file name. You should assign the input an id attribute, like:

```
dp.on('success', function(file, response){
  $("#thumbnail_dropzone").append($('<input type="hidden" name="listing_images[]" value="'+response.aFileName+'" id="'+response.someId+'"/>'));
});
```

Then you can use the id to destroy, i mean remove, the hidden input. See

```
dp.on('removedfile', function(file){
$("#response.someid").remove();
});
```